# What are potential strategies for using Git with a large-ish game project?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

A bit of background on my problem, followed by some questions:

My team uses SVN for a number of game development projects, and it has served us well for the past several years. However, we've recently been exploring whether we ought to move to Git, for several reasons:

- We believe that the branching capabilities of Git will open up beneficial coding workflows and practices that are either difficult or impossible in SVN (feature branches, code reviews before merging, pull requests).
- Some newer members of our team come to us from a game company that uses Git, and they lament the lack of feature X or Y in SVN.
- SVN-related tools seem to be updated/maintained less than they were. In short, Git and similar are popular, while SVN is becoming less popular.

We wanted to use Bitbucket because we could more easily collaborate with external contractors than with a SVN repo behind our company firewall.

We used the git-svn tool to convert our project to a Git repo. The Git repo ended up being 6GB with all the history! Unfortunately, this is too large for Bitbucket and Github, who both enforce 1-2GB limits.

This has caused a bit of a "crisis of faith" as to whether we were making the right decision by switching from SVN to Git. You can find plenty of opinions online that Git isn't good for game development, or that binary files are a headache. Our plan was to keep source art files in SVN, but any "final" art assets for the game would exist in SVN. Additionally, a set of shared libraries would exist in separate Git repos linked to our game's repo (using subtrees or some dependency management system, most likely).

I'm looking for answers/feedback on a couple fronts:

1. Is 6GB too unwieldy for a Git repo? Will people be able to work with it effectively, or will it likely be unresponsive or difficult to push to a remote?
2. Is it considered reasonable to split up a large Git repo into several smaller repos to sidestep any "large repo" problems? Thinking about it, it seems like it could be a big mess, and structuring a project to accommodate version control limitations doesn't sit well with me. Cloning also seems problematic - do you need to clone each repo separately, or is it possible to do in one go?
3. Have others successfully used Git for game dev projects of this type, and if so, what strategies were used to make the workflow as straightforward as possible? Will we be spending more time wrangling the version control to our bidding than actually developing the game!?

Any feedback or insight from those who have had to tread this road would be great!

Comment: as long as you have not yet migrated, think about Mercurial+LargeFiles - more profit, a **lot less** headache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Git for game dev, but for multimedia dev that had large video assets.

What we did is similar to what you suggest; we kept the large assets in a separate submodule. It took a little bit of training (and possibly some wrapper scripts that made the common cases easier, I don't recall precisely) to get everyone used to working with the submodules, but once they were it worked out reasonably smoothly.

We even allowed the assets to change in the submodule, and once it got too big we just created a new repo and switch the submodule over to that. That meant you didn't get history between the two parts, but since they were the binaries that didn't matter too much, and you can always use `git replace` to stitch the history of two repositories together to get the full history if you wanted to pay the costs of checking out the large binary repo.

So yes, I would say that Git can work out for this use case, as long as you keep your main repository reasonably sized and text only, and manage your assets separately. Whether that's in SVN and exported somehow, in a Git submodule that you break history on, or via something like [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) is something you'll probably have to figure out depending on trying out a couple of approaches and seeing which one you think works best.

Comment: Since writing the above question, our project is still hosted on SVN. However, we now have another game project with a lot of art assets that is using Git "LFS" (large file support) successfully. So, that appears to be a workable solution as well.